# Do we have for Service Agrement License (SLA) feasibility in offline ( for mobile/Tab ) in dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

Do we have Service Agrement License (SLA) feasibility in offline ( for mobile/Tab ) in dynamics CRM ?

suggestions are appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

As long as your entity has the SLA capability (i.e enabled, with corresponding field) Then it's possible to 'Enable for Mobile Offline'

[image]

If your using the *Case* entity (based on the Incident entity), which has a SLA built in, this entity is by default set to enabled for Offline sync.

For more information please check out the MSFT documentation page, which mentions SLA:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/administering-dynamics-365/dn531159(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#BKMK_CustomEntity